# How can I identify sentences that have a space before a dot '.' and remove this space

Tags: python, string

Given a random text, how can I identify sentences that have a space before a dot '.', and remove this space?

```
my_text = 'The pressure is already being monitored. We will report the results soon . kind regards.'
```

Expected result (`We will report the results soon .` => `We will report the results soon.`):

```
my_text = 'The pressure is already being monitored. We will report the results soon. kind regards.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

my_text = 'The pressure is already being monitored. We will report the results soon . kind regards.'

res = re.sub(r'\s+\.', r'.', my_text)
print(res)
```

Comment: What's this doing?

Comment: @PeterWood It's using regular expression to do the substitute work.

Comment: What's a regular expression? Why does this one work?

Answer (score 0):

```
k=[]                          # Take an empty list
for x in my_text.split('.'):  # Split with all the '.'
  if x==0:                    # For the First iteration do not add '.'
    k.append(x.rstrip())      # rstrip() will remove any number of extra spaces
  else:
    k.append(x.rstrip()+'.')  # Add '.' after each sentence.
''.join(k[:-1])               # Removing the last '.' since it will be inserted twice
```